# Is is possible to use a combination of ValidationRules and INotifyDataErrorInfo for wpf validation?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, idataerrorinfo, inotifydataerrorinfo

In WPF there are 3 ways to do validation:

- Validation Rules
- `IDataErrorInfo`
- `INotifyDataErrorInfo`

Is it possible to use a combination of these at the same time? For my needs, I would like to validate new rules with the flexibility of INotifyDataErrorInfo, but don't want to interfere with existing ValidationRules for the same object I want to validate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. Mixing the different source of errors**

Yes you can mix the three kind of Validation you quote :

- `ValidationRules` are fine for GUI(surface) validation
- `IDataErrorInfo` is implemented on the view model/business object. It is fine for more business oriented validation
- `INotifyDataErrorInfo` is also implemented on the view model/business object. It adds possibility of multiple errors on a given field and also adds asynchronous validations (i.e. a server or a thread can take time to answer to the valildation).

That last source of error is really more longer to implement

**2. Taking errors into account**

The most difficult is to take into account the different sources of error when you want to prevent a window from being closed if data is not valid.

ValidationRules error must be looked up in the GUI bindings, because the invalid data doesn't get to the business object/ViewModel.

`IDataErrorInfo` and `INotifiDataErrorInfo` can be looked in the ViewModel layer.

Regards

Comment: I used the combination of the two and I run into some side effects that I can tolerate for now.

Comment: Of course it can be tolerable, and even useful ;-). Because these aren't the same kind of validations, they can be complementary.

Comment: @disklosr what were the side effects you were talking about? I'm about to implement some validation rules along existing INotifyDataErrorInfor implementation as I don't want user to add specific characters into my model. But if they are side effects it would be interesting to know and that will make the answer more informative.